# URL to download a csv file using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, vba7

Is there any way I can download the csv file from below link for example.
"https://www.nseindia.com/corporates-pit?index=equities&symbol=WABCOINDIA&csv=true"

Tried the below code but no luck.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
    Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Public Sub Valuebuy()

myfile = "https://www.nseindia.com/corporates-pit?index=equities&symbol=WABCOINDIA&csv=true"

  Dim targetFile As String, targetUrl As String, returnVal As Double
    Target = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/corporates-pit?index=equities&symbol=WABCOINDIA&csv=true"
    strSavePath = "C:\testdownload.txt"
    returnVal = URLDownloadToFile(0, Target, strSavePath, 0, 0)
    If returnVal = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Download ok!"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Error"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: "no luck" is not a useful description of exactly what happens when you run your code

Comment: `Set wb = WorkBooks.open(myFile)` should work

Comment: @TimWilliams, thanks for the reply, I am not able to download the file, can u try from ur end. Its saying server is busy

Comment: I get a message to check the address

Comment: my bad, apologies @TimWilliams the correct URL is below one https://www.nseindia.com/api/corporates-pit?index=equities&symbol=WABCOINDIA&csr=true .Also can u try for incognito window inchrome

Comment: Resource not found

Comment: can u refresh again twice, it came to me. This is a url which i got when inspecting a webpage. I can access through powerquery but not with vba

Comment: I tried it also, with same results as @TimWilliams "Resource Not Found"

Comment: probably this site uses cookies and cannot work the given URL. any idea how can we get through vba code by providing cookie information.

Comment: Just tried it again and the response is a `JSON` document

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, yes, but I am not able to get the data from the code provided, is there any alternative way  I can download to excel sheet

Comment: I'd probably use the `GET` method but since the response here is so slow (using any method), when I tried it a few times it timed out before anything loaded.

Comment: I also get "Resource Not Found" error. Where did you obtain that URL? Also why you don;t use an API?  https://www1.nseindia.com/technology/content/nnf/WEB_CBRICS_PROTOCOL_1.2.pdf